# scraping text hidden (?) behind javascript object

Tags: javascript, python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy and I would like to extract the text element. This is the webpage I'd like to scrape 
http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/3131289_-vitodens-222-f-13-kw-viessmann.html

I am using the following xpath command:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//tr'):
sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/text()').extract()
```

There are products (lines in the table) in the html code where that works just fine. However, there are cases where a javascript is embedded directly before the text:

```
<td class="title">
  <a class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt" ... >
    <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>
    text I need 
  </a>
</td>
```

In these cases I cannot retrieve the "text I need".

I have also searched and tried out several other xpath options, like getting all child nodes. These are the variants i tried:

```
        # item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/script[@type="text/javascript"]/following-sibling::*').extract()
        # item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/script[@type="text/javascript"]/node()').extract()
        item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/text()[0]').extract()
        ## item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/node()').extract()
        ## item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
        ## item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/node()').extract()
        ## item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/text()').extract()
        ## item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[2]').extract()
        ## item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/*').extract()
        ## item['longtitle'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/script[@type="text/javascript"]/text()').extract()
```

but I keep failing.

I'd be happy for any help. Thank you.

Comment: `//td[@class="title"]/a[@class="offer-title link-2 webtrekk wt-prompt"]/text()[2]` because <script>  splitss text - there are empty string and your text

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I tried the second and then the thrid and fourth element of the split text: [2],[3] and [4]. They are all empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like with respect to those cells where the `<script>` tag exists, there is no text in the HTML node. From some quick inspection of their JavaScript (which happens to be unminified), it looks like those cells get populated with text when the JS runs. So you're not going crazy, those cells definitely don't have any text in them.

To get that text, you'll need to either follow the link and get the title from the next page (which will have to be conditional somehow, since not every link leads to the same site), or you'll need to pull the page using some JS engine, like Selenium (`pip install selenium`):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> my_driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> my_driver.get(response.url)
>>> results = my_driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[contains(@class, "modular")]//tr[.//a]')
>>> for row in results:
...     print row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[@class="title"]/a').text
Viess­mann Vi­to­dens 222-F Kom­pakt-Brenn­wert­ther­me, 13 kW, VT100, HE ohne Ab­gas­pa­ket, ohne An­schluss-Set Viess­mann
Viess­mann Vi­to­dens 222-F wahl­wei­se 13,19, 26 oder 35 kW + Vi­to­tro­nic 100 oder 200 (Re­ge­lung: Vi­to­tro­nic 100, max. Wär­me­leis­tung (KW): 13)
Paket Vi­to­dens 222-W 13KW mit Vi­to­tro­nic 200, La­de­spei­cher und Mon­ta­ge­hil­fe AP
Viess­mann Vi­to­dens 222-F nach Wahl, 13, 19 & 26 kW, Gas-Brenn­wert-Kom­pakt­ge­rä­te (Ab­gas­pa­ket: Ohne, An­schluss-Set: Ohne, Re­ge­lung: Vi­to­tro­nic 100, Heiz­krei­s­pum­pe: Hoch­ef­fi­zi­ent, Leis­tung: 13kW)
Vi­to­dens 222-F 13 kW mit Vi­to­tro­nic 100 HC1B, hoch­ef­fi­zi­ent
Viess­mann Paket Vi­to­dens 222-F 13 kW Vi­to­tro­nic
Viess­mann Paket Vi­to­dens 222-F 13 kW Vi­to­tro­nic
Viess­mann Vi­to­dens 222-F B2TA mit Vi­to­tro­nic 100 3,2 - 13,0 kW
Viess­mann Vi­to­dens 222-F B2SA mit Vi­to­tro­nic 100 3,2 - 13,0 kW
Viess­mann 222-F Gasther­me, 13 kW, B2SA010, Spei­cher in­nen­be­heizt, Auf­putz l/r Viess­mann
Viess­mann 222-F Gasther­me, 13 kW, B2SA007, Spei­cher in­nen­be­heizt, Auf­putz oben Viess­mann
Vi­to­dens 222-F mit Vi­to­tro­nic 200, La­de­spei­cher 3,2 - 13,0 kW
Viess­mann Vi­to­dens 222-F BS2A mit Vi­to­tro­nic 200 3,2 - 13,0 kW
Vi­to­dens 222-F 13KW mit Spei­cher mit Vi­to­tro­nic 200 Kom­pakt­ge­rät
Vi­to­tro­nic 200 HO1B, Mon­ta­ge­hil­fe AP 3,2 - 13,0 kW, Auf­putz-Mon­ta­ge
```

And there you have it. 15 results.

Note: This functionality would obviously be better in a downloader middleware, so as not to make multiple requests to the same URL, but I'll leave that to you ;)